# Little problem with arm movement in my character's walk cycle

Tags: animation

It's obvious not right when both arms move backward. There are some little 'Khực khực' there. Oh sorry I could only describe that in my language LOL.
   Anyways, that's like some robotic displacement causing false action (false movement?). Oh just take a look in the blend. file here LOL

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arm IK control bones (Arm.L and Arm.R) are positioned too far in parts of animation, so the arms need to extend too much and are no longer bent in elbow. That causes the elbow popping in the walk cycle.

Also the same bones are not looped, so that causes another discontinuity when looping the animation.

Keyframe these bones more carefully to not overextend the arms and loop them and the animation will be fine.